# Logical implication with undefined property

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm confused whether statements like "If a=0 then 1/a = 5" is true or false? If we assume a=0, then with attempt to prove by contradiction, we assum also 1/a is not equal to 5, then this would lead to contradiction since 1/a is not defined, so 1/a = 5. Or is it because 1/a is not defined, hence 1/a is not equal to 5?

Comment: An undefined thing cannot equal a defined thing, or at best it is note defined whether they are equal. It may however be instructive to look at the contrapositive "If $\frac1a\ne 5$, then $a\ne 0$". :)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen So since the statement is false, the negation must be correct, so the statement "a = 0 and 1/a ≠ 5" is correct? Am I right? Thanks.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2774155/305738) goes into much more detail about what $1/a$ means mathematically.

Answer (score 1):

For all non-zero real values of $a$, the implication "If $a=0$ then $1/a=5$" would true since the antecedent would always be false and the consequent would be either true or false depending the particular value of $a$.

For $a=0$, the truth value for this implication would be indeterminate. While the truth value of the antecedent would be true, you would not be able to assign one to the consequent.

Comment: Assuming a=0 ,can i ask why you can't assign truth value for the consequent? If we assume that the implication is true we get a contradiction ($\frac{1}{a}$ is undefined and defined), so the negation must be true, so the whole implication is false.Therefore the primes is true and the conclusion is false. What i'm missing ?

Comment: @yousefmagableh From the field axioms, there is no multiplicative inverse (reciprocal) defined for zero on the reals. So, we cannot assign a truth value (true or false) to 1/0 = 5.

Comment: But the statement x=5 means: x is defined and has the value 5. Since $ \frac {1}{0} $ is undefined, then saying  $ \frac {1}{0} $=5 is like saying: $ \frac {1}{0} $ is undefined and defined at the same time, so it's false statement. Or not ?

Comment: @yousefmagableh "Undefined" is not a formal notion in logic. Informally, in this case, it only means that the definition of multiplicative inverse does not specify any value for the multiplicative inverse of zero.

Comment: I can't see how is that relevant. Regardless of what is the precise meaning of undefined. Still the statement can be translated into a form of two mutually exclusive statements( defined and undefined ) that are true at the same time, which is a contradiction. If I can say: It is not the case that $\frac {1}{0}$=5 ( what ever the interpretation of that statement is ) is true statement, then it has to be false. There is no other alternative if we are talking in the context of propositional logic.

Comment: Another example : If I say blue = cat, although this statement has no meaning, but since i can't say it is true ( "blue" is not an identity of  "cat" ), then it is a false statement. If i'm wrong ( which is very possible ), I want to know what is wrong with saying: blue=cat is false statement.

Comment: @yousefmagableh Your use of the word "contradiction" suggests a formal proof that obtains a result of the form P and not P for some logical proposition P. Since "defined" and "undefined" are not formalized (at least not in classical logic), I don't think you would be able to obtain a contradiction of the form X is defined and X is not defined. In practice, you simply won't be able to formally prove or disprove that 1/0 = 5. You will come to a dead end (an impasse) in your proof.

Comment: If I define x=5 as follows: x is defined and x has the value 5. Then 1/0 =5 by definition is equivalent to the statement 1/0 is defined and has the value 5. But since 1/0 is undefined, then 1/0 is defined and undefined and has the value 5. Which is a contradiction. Assuming my definition holds, is my argument valid ?

Comment: @yousefmagableh AFAIK "x is defined" is not a notion that is formalized in any formal system based on classical logic. Do you have something else in mind?

Comment: I think I understand your point. What are the subjects "textbooks" that go more deeply in this, like what is formalized in formal logic and what is not ?

Comment: @yousefmagableh None come to mind. Perhaps other readers can suggest a reference?